# How to know when paste event triggered in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, uipasteboard

I have been working on Rich text editor app in IOS.

My aim is to detect the triggering of a Paste event in `UITextView`, And prevent the default paste operation. Then, I'll convert content in the `UIPasteboard` to my Editor app format and append the converted `nsattributedstring` into `UITextView`.

I have referred the following link:

[Detect when a user clicks the paste button in a UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123647/detect-when-a-user-clicks-the-paste-button-in-a-uitextview).

I think solution of the problem is related to `UITextField` and not for `UITextView`(Correct me, If i'm wrong).

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think creating a custom textview and override to paste: method will help you.

```
- (void)paste:(id)sender
{
    [super paste:sender];

    NSLog(@"PASTE!!");
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the delegate of the UITextView for this function to trigger.

Comment: Check my answer to the similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35464829/1630623