# How to paste image from pasteboard on UITextView?

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I have the following code on a keyboard extensión

```
let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
var image = UIImage(named: "myimage");
pasteboard.image = image;
```

This doesn't work on a `UITextView` I have on my container application, paste context menu never shows up. It works on other applications like "messages" but not on mine.

My code works if I try to paste text instead of an image using `string` property so I'm quite near.

I could need to set up my text view different but I don't know how. I've changed "Text" from "Plain" to "Attributed" but still not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UITextView` only supports pasting text out of the box. You can subclass it and add support for pasting images, which can be implemented using [attributed string text attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26489358/1445366).

[NSHipster's writeup on `UIMenuController`](http://nshipster.com/uimenucontroller/) and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1146587/1445366) explain the paste logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then any of the text controls where the image paste works are custom subclasses and not built in controls?

Comment: It's correct that none of them are built-in controls. They might be something besides custom subclasses, but a subclass is how I'd implement it in your case.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't work if implemented in UITextView subclass, but I tried it in the UIViewController containing the textView and it worked:

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {

    if (action == @selector(paste:)) {
        return [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string != nil || [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image != nil;
        //if you want to do this for specific textView add && [yourTextView isFirstResponder] to if statement
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];

}

-(void)paste:(id)sender {
    //do your action here
}
```

Comment: this is objC right? how can I add it to my swiftui code?

Comment: This question is not intended for SwiftUI, it's only for UITextView, which is a part od UIKit. You'll have to find or create a question for SwiftUI

Answer (score 5):

Create an `NSTextAttachment` from the image and an attributed string with the TextAttachment. Then set the attributedText property of the `UITextView`. Subclass UITextView and override the `paste(_:)` method:

```
override func paste(_ sender: Any?) {
    let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
    textAttachment.image = UIPasteboard.general.image
    attributedText = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)
}
```

Comment: mhhh, but how do I trigger this if "paste" context menu never shows up?

Comment: @TimmyO'Tool edited my answer. You have to subclass UITextView and override the paste function.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be checking about this. In any case I didn't want t paste in my application, just wanted to be sure that I implemented correctly the copy feature to make it work with third party applications. Now  I know that the problems is that UITextView doesn't support this out of the box and not a bug on my code.

Comment: I'm confused. What was the answer to @StackOverflower's question, "but how do I trigger this if 'paste' context menu never shows up?"

Comment: I cannnot override paste for uitextview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73739276/how-can-i-override-paste-so-i-can-paste-images-in-a-uitextview

Comment: I got an error that I cannot override : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73739276/how-can-i-override-paste-so-i-can-paste-images-in-a-uitextview